# installing ubuntu 18.04 on Microsoft surface pro 5

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, uefi, windows-10, surface

I have prepared the **bootable USB disk** with **Rufus** and **Disabled the secure boot** (Secure Boot Certificate keyset is selected None). However, when I restart the laptop a page name **BitLocker** (recovery key) loads. From here whatever option that I chose is a dead end and I do not see any page/option related to installing ubuntu. Am I missing some steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to keep (some) of your Windows Data:

BitLocker encrypts your data on the Windows partition. I recommend you to enable secure boot, so that BitLocker makes the file readable for windows. Then you can [disable BitLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/disable-bitlocker).

Then you can anagin disable Secureboot. Then you wont get a message from BitLocker.

### Boot from USB

Windows 10 gives you [an option to boot into an USB-device](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023511/surface-boot-surface-from-a-usb-device). Please leave a comment if you get somewhere a problem.

In short: Settings > Update & security > Recovery > Advanced startup > Restart Now

Comment: thanks for the solution. Disabled Bitlocker and it went to the installation page.